# dynamic php id JQuery ajax output will not change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

After a button is selected on a fresh page, all information are there, but whenever another is clicked, the first info is still there and wont change until the page is refreshed.

Help me pass this will ya?

button

```
<?php while($b = mysqli_fetch_assoc($equery)): ?>
                <button  type="button" onclick="modal(<?=$b['id'];?>)" class="w3-btn w3-border" style="width: 260px; display: inline-block; margin: 9px">
                    <img src="">
                    <h3><?php echo $b['product'];?></h3>
                    <h5>Descritopm</h5>
                    <h6></h6>
                </button>
            <?php endwhile;?>
```

js:

```
 function modal(id){
                var data = {"id" : id};
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url : <?=BASEURL;?>+'includes/modal.php',
                    method : "post",
                    data : data,
                    success: function(data){
                        jQuery('body').append(data);
                        jQuery('#mod').modal('show');
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("IDK")
                    }
                });
            }
```

modal:

```
    <?php
require_once '../core/init.php';
$id = $_POST['id'];
$id =(int)$id;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM aisle WHERE id = '$id'";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

?>

<!-- Modal -->
<?php ob_start();?>
<div id="mod" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h3 class="modal-title w3-center"><?=$product['product'];?></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p><?=$product['aisle'];?></p>
        <p>$<?=$product['price'];?></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<?php echo ob_get_clean();?>
```

Comment: I create a project with your codes, but I can't find any problem, so what is wrong?

Comment: When i click on a product, the same information keeps showing up whenever I click another product. I have to keep refreshing my page whenever I want to see another product's info

Comment: you can check my answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
jQuery('body').append(data);
```

This line will `append` more modal and many modals will appear on your page. You should follow this way. Create a div tag called `contents_from_ajax` inside body tag and then use this.

```
jQuery('#contents_from_ajax').html(data);
```

This code will remove all old modals and create a new one instead of append, and then it will work fine.

Hope this help

---